# Bar plot with groupby

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

My categorical variable `case_status` takes on four unique values. I have data from 2014 to 2016. I would like to plot the distribution of `case_status` grouped by year. I try the following:

```py
df.groupby('year').case_status.value_counts().plot.barh()
```

And I get the following plot:

[image: output]

However, I want the following plot:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to sort the values in the plot? For example in this case, from bottom to top you would have Certified, Certified-withdrawn, Withdrawn, Denied. Thanks!

Comment: @Julioolvera it's pretty late but I added an answer below that sorts the labels, in case you're interested. Cheers.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I think you need add [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for `DataFrame`:

```
df.groupby('year').case_status.value_counts().unstack().plot.barh()
```

Also is possible change level:

```
df.groupby('year').case_status.value_counts().unstack(0).plot.barh()
```

Comment: `.unstack(0)` made what I want

Answer (score 1):

Another way to plot bar plots grouped by year is to use `pivot_table()` instead; pass the column that becomes the x-axis label to `index=` and the grouper to `columns=` and plot the `size`. Note that since you can pass any function to `aggfunc=`, it is more general than `value_counts()`; with `pivot_table`, we can plot e.g. `mean`, `sum`, etc.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': np.random.choice([2014, 2015, 2016], size=3000), 'case_status': [*['Certified']*2500, *['Certified-Withdrawn']*300, *['Withdrawn']*100, *['Denied']*100]})
df.pivot_table(index='case_status', columns='year', aggfunc='size').plot.barh();
#  ^^^^^^^^^^^ pivot_table call here                               ^^^^ barplot call here
```

If the x-ticklabels have to be sorted in some order, then (given they come from the dataframe index) you can sort the index before the plotting by using `loc[]`.

Let's say, you want the data sorted in the `index_order` below. Then you can sort the index by passing the **reverse** of this order to `loc` and call `plot`.

```py
index_order = ['Certified', 'Certified-Withdrawn', 'Withdrawn', 'Denied']
df.pivot_table(index='case_status', columns='year', aggfunc='size').loc[reversed(index_order)].plot.barh()
```

[image: result]