# Can I get proportions when using pandas groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-science, visualization

Currently I am using the method specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48238305/bar-plot-with-groupby) to generate the following plot: 
[image]

My code is :

```
grouped_data = df.groupby(["ssc_b", "hsc_b"]).status.value_counts().unstack(2);
grouped_data.plot.bar(title = "Placements by Board of Education", rot = 45).set_xlabel("(SSC, HSC)");
```

But I would like to change the values within group to represent the proportions within ech group rather than the counts themselves, since the number of samples per group varies quite a bit. I feel that this would make it easier to compare the groups. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: you can try to normalise the unstacked column. You can check an [example here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51747539/normalize-data-and-plot-as-stacked-bar-plot-with-python-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `normalize=True` to `value_counts`:

```
grouped_data = (df.groupby(["ssc_b", "hsc_b"]).status
                  .value_counts(normalize=True).unstack(2)
               )
```

Also a side note: Python does not require `;` at the end of the lines.

Comment: Thank you! I think I need to learn how the navigate docs better. The semicolon was actually added to supress the messgae for the plot in the second line. The first one was an acciden :P